# Can I use RegEx to replace US dates in 12 hour format to UK dates in 24 hour format?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a .dat text file that was exported from a web-based platform on a machine with date and time format set as m/d/yyyy HH:MM AM/PM. (so 9am on 1st May 1999 is 5/1/1999 9:00 AM)

I need these dates to be in UK format and times in 24 hour format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm) - eg 01/05/1999 09:00.

I am using notepad++ to edit and can find and replace the DATES using the following:

Step 1 (Month Padding):

FIND: ,([0-9])/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)
REPLACE: ,0\1/\2/\3

Step 2 (Date Padding):

FIND: ([0-9]+)/+([0-9])/+([0-9]+)
REPLACE: \1/0\2/\3

Step 3 (US Conversion):

FIND: ([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)
REPLACE: \2/\1/\3

Can anybody help me also convert the times?

Comment: To convert PM hours to 24-hours, you need to perform an (arithmetic) addition. Regex is the wrong tool for that. Unless you are willing to replace 01 with 13, 02 with 14, 03 with 15, ...etc, all with individual replace operations.

Answer (score 1):

To convert PM hours to 24-hours, you need to perform an (arithmetic) addition.

Regex is the wrong tool for that. Unless you are willing to replace "01 PM" with "13", "02 PM" with "14", "03 PM" with "15", ...etc, all with individual replace operations.

But if you want to do it in only a few operations, then you need a scripting/programming language.

For instance, the following snippet will do the conversion in one go. Run the snippet here, paste your input in the left box, and find the result in the right box.

```js
const [input, output] = document.querySelectorAll("textarea, button");

(input.oninput = () => output.value = input.value.replace(
    /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d{4}) (\d+):(\d+) ([AP])M/g,
    (_, M, d, y, h, m, p) => `${d}/${M}/${y} ${(h%12)+12*(p>'A')}:${m}`
                            .replace(/\b\d\b/g, "0$&")
))();
```

```css
textarea { width: 50%; height: 98%; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0}
body { height: 100vh; margin: 0 }
```

```html
<textarea>
5/1/1999 12:05 AM
12/31/2000 9:18 AM
2/28/2001 4:56 PM
4/9/2023 12:19 PM
5/24/2019 7:23 PM
</textarea><textarea readonly></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The wanted changes can be done with one Notepad++ replace. Both the Regex and the replacement text are complex.

PM times need 12 added. RegExs do not allow addition, however Notepad++ RegExs provide conditionals. Thus we can use RegEx replacements with the meaning:

```
if 1pm the replace with "13"
else if 2pm then replace with "14"
... and so on
```

The example in the question is `5/1/1999 9:00 AM` which has single digits in three places. To match the month with an optional leading digit we can use `(\d)?\d` then use the replacment `(?1$1:0)$2`. This is interpreted as if there is a leading digit (the `?1`) then insert it (the `$1`) otherwise insert a zero (`0`). Similar optional digits are used in several other places.

The minutes value is between the hour value and the AM/PM. Maybe there are other ways of doing the conditionals to keep the values correct.

Use the following RegEx as search text:

```
^(\d)?(\d)/(\d)?(\d)/(\d\d\d\d) ((((\d)?\d:\d\d) am)|((0?0)|(0?1)|(0?2)|(0?3)|(0?4)|(0?5)|(0?6)|(0?7)|(0?8)|(0?9)|(10)|(11))(:\d\d) pm)$
```

Use this for the replacement:

```
(?3$3:0)$4/(?1$1:0)$2/$5 (?7(?9:0)$8)(?{11}12${23})(?{12}13${23})(?{13}14${23})(?{14}15${23})(?{15}16${23})(?{16}17${23})(?{17}18${23})(?{18}19${23})(?{19}20${23})(?{20}21${23})(?{21}22${23})(?{22}23${23})
```

**Explanation of the Regex:**

```
^                       Start of line
(\d)?(\d)               Month with optional leading digit, captures 1 and 2
/
(\d)?(\d)               Days with optional leading digits, captures 3 and 4
/
(\d\d\d\d)              Year, four digits, capture 5
                        One space
(                       Bracket capture 6, to distinguish AM and PM times
  (                       Bracket capture 7, to catch the whole AM time
    (                       The AM time, capture 8, 
      (\d)?\d:\d\d            The time with optional leading digit, in capture 9
    ) am                    The "AM"
  )
  |                     Alternatives within capture 6
  (                       Bracket capture 10, to catch the whole PM time
    (0?0)                   0pm with optional leading zero, capture 11
    |                     OR
    (0?1)                   1pm with optional leading zero, capture 12
    |                     OR
    (0?2)|(0?3)|(0?4)|(0?5)|(0?6)|(0?7)|(0?8)|(0?9)|(10)|(11), captures 13 to 22
                            2pm to 11pm
  )
  (:\d\d)                 The colon and minutes, capture 23
                          One space
  pm                      "PM"
)                       End of capture 6
$                       End of line
```

**Explanation of the replacement:**

```
(?3$3:0)$4               Day: If leading digit present then insert it,
                             otherwise a zero. Insert the second digit
/
(?1$1:0)$2               Month
/
$5                       Year
(?7(?9:0)$8)             If AM time found (`?7`) then insert the time value,
                             if only one hour digit add a leading zero
(?{11}12${23})           If 0PM (`?{11}`) then insert "12" and the colon and minutes (`${23}`)
(?{12}13${23})           If 1PM (`?{12}`) then insert "13" and the colon and minutes (`${23}`)
(?{13}14${23})           Similarly for the remaining PM times
(?{14}15${23})
(?{15}16${23})
(?{16}17${23})
(?{17}18${23})
(?{18}19${23})
(?{19}20${23})
(?{20}21${23})
(?{21}22${23})
(?{22}23${23})
```

**Testing:**

From this input text:

```
5/1/1999 9:00 AM
1/4/2021 2:03 PM
02/15/2021 3:04 PM
3/6/2021 4:05 PM
04/17/2021 5:06 PM
5/8/1999 6:07 PM
06/09/2023 7:08 PM
7/10/2022 8:09 PM
08/22/2021 9:10 PM
9/24/2021 10:11 PM
10/25/2021 11:12 PM
1/4/2021 1:15 PM
02/15/2021 1:16 AM
3/6/2021 2:17 AM
04/17/2021 3:18 AM
5/8/1999 4:19 AM
```

Produced these results:

```
01/05/1999 09:00
04/01/2021 14:03
15/02/2021 15:04
06/03/2021 16:05
17/04/2021 17:06
08/05/1999 18:07
09/06/2023 19:08
10/07/2022 20:09
22/08/2021 21:10
24/09/2021 22:11
25/10/2021 23:12
04/01/2021 13:15
15/02/2021 01:16
06/03/2021 02:17
17/04/2021 03:18
08/05/1999 04:19
```

**Commentary:**

Both the RegEx and the replacement are horribly long and horribly complex. They are good example of why RegExs are the wrong solution for some problems. Creating this Regex and replacement took too long. Expecting to use them in a production environment where changes may be needed would mean someone else would need to understand them. Complex RegExs are difficult to maintain.

Captures 6 and 10 (and possibly 7) might be converted to non-capturing groups.

Having crafted these expressions I am wondering whether a time of "0:15 PM" is valid, so perhaps there is already a fault in these expressions.

These expression form an interesting exercise in showing what can be done with RegExs, but I strongly recommend finding another approach to the problem.